# Filling a mysql table combining data from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
Table 1     Table2
id_1        id_2 name
1           10    name1
2           20    name2
3
4
5
```

I need a query to get this another one, where for each id_1 the result gets as many registers as table 2 has.

```
Table3
id_3 id_1 id_2 name
1    1    10    name1
2    1    20    name2
3    2    10    name1
4    2    20    name2
5    3    10    name1
6    3    20    name2
7    4    10    name1
8    4    20    name2
9    5    10    name1
10   5    20    name2
```

Could you help me?
Thanks

EDIT:

Well, thanks to both of you.

Finally I got an easy solution.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2
```

I didn´t know the **CROSS JOIN** operator. And that gives you the combination of each register from the first table with each register from the second.

Thanks again

Comment: try and create that table first. You would need a join http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 SELECT t1.id_1,t2.id_2,t2.name FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should work:

```
insert into table3 (id_1,id_2,name) values select id_1,id_2,name from table1,table2;
```

I guess that `id_3` is an autoincrement